# Poor man's LaTeX

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

You are transported in a parallel universe where people write mathematical equations on computers as ASCII art by hand. As a LaTeX addict, this is totally unacceptable, and you ought to automate this process somewhat.

Your goal is to write a program that outputs an ASCII version of an equation inputed as a LaTeX math command.

#### Mandatory LaTeX commands to support

- Sum: the LaTeX command for a sum is `\sum_{lower bound}^{upper bound}`

  The ASCII figure you have to use for sums is:

  ```
  upper bound
      ___ 
      \  `
      /__,
  lower bound
  ```
- Product: the LaTeX command for a product is `\prod_{lower bound}^{upper bound}`

  The ASCII figure you have to use for products is:

  ```
  upper bound
      ____
      |  |
      |  |
  lower bound
  ```
- Fraction: the LaTeX command for fractions is `\frac{numerator}{denominator}`

  The ASCII figure you have to use for fractions is:

  ```
   numerator
  -----------
  denominator
  ```

Anything that is not one of those three commands is displayed as is. For example, `\sum{i=3}^{e^10}\frac{3x+5}{2}`should be displayed as

```
e^10
___  3x+5
\  ` ----
/__,  2
i=3
```

#### Inputs

The input is a LaTeX command passed as a string (or your language's equivalent to strings). LaTeX commands can be nested, for instance `\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{3}` is a valid input. Inputs are supposed to be always correct (no need to check LaTeX's syntax in your code). Inputs will only consist of the three LaTeX commands presented above and 'text' that you won't need to format.

LaTeX commands will always come with the syntax presented above, i.e. sums and products will always have upper and lower bounds (although they can be empty) and there will always be a numerator and denominator for fractions.

We assume that the bounds of sums and products are at most 4 characters long (= the width of the sum and product symbols), so that you don't have to worry about possible overlap issues. For similar reasons, we assume that the bounds are just 'text' and will never be LaTeX commands, e.g. `\sum_{\sum_{1}^{2}}^{1}` is not a valid input.

#### Outputs

Your program's output is the ASCII representation of the LaTeX command you were given as input.

Your program has to take horizontal alignment into account: for instance, the bounds of the sum or the product have to be horizontally aligned with the sum or product symbol (which are both 4 characters wide).
If the bound has an odd number of characters, it does not matter whether it is one character off to the right or to left of the center, whichever is fine. The fraction's line has to be as long as the numerator or the denominator, whichever is the longest.

Your program has to take vertical alignment into account: for instance, `\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{3} = \frac{1}{6}` should be displayed as

```
1
-
2   1
- = -
3   6
```

For sums and products, since the symbols are 4 characters high, the vertical center is assumed to be the second line from the top.

Horizontal spacing is assumed to be correct in the given input, i.e. the spaces in the input should be displayed in the output.

#### Test cases

- Input `abc = 2`

  Output `abc = 2`
- Input `e = \sum_{n=0}^{+inf} \frac{1}{n!}`

  Output

  ```
      +inf
      ___  1
  e = \  ` --
      /__, n!
      n=0
  ```
- Input `e^x = 1 + \frac{x}{1 - \frac{x}{2 + x - ...}}`

  Output

  ```
                   x
  e^x = 1 + ---------------
                     x
            1 - -----------
                2 + x - ...
  ```
- Input `\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m} 2j}{i + 1}`

  Output

  ```
         m
        ___
        \  ` 2j
   n    /__,
  ____  j=0
  |  |  -------
  |  |   i + 1
  i=1
  ```
- Input `\frac{sum}{prod} = \sum_{frac}^{prod} sum`

  Output

  ```
         prod
  sum    ___
  ---- = \  ` sum
  prod   /__,
         frac
  ```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins.

Comment: Nice first challenge. It looks pretty difficult; I'm excited to see some solutions.

Comment: @Alex A. I originally intended to also have integrals, square roots and expandable parenthesis, but that seemed a bit too much...

Comment: Haha yeah, that would be crazy hard.

Comment: For extra fun, there should be a case like `\frac{sum}{prod} = \sum_{frac}^{prod} sum`

Comment: @Sp3000: You'd have to backslash `frac`, `prod`, and `sum`. But that brings up a good point: Can we assume that sums and products will always have the form `\cmd_{lb}^{ub}`? That is, do we have to support big sigma and big pi on their own?

Comment: @Alex A. yes, there will always be the curvy brackets for upper bound and lower bounds, though it may be empty inside them, in which case you don't display anything

Comment: @AlexA. No, I mean [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vedrK.png), which I'm guessing would be [this](http://pastebin.com/KY38BHZB).

Comment: @Sp3000 that's actually a good example, I'll include it so that parsing the backslash or the brackets is necessary

Comment: ambiguous fraction stacking is bad. higher levels of fraction should have wider bars.

Comment: @sparr Ambiguity should be cleared by vertical alignement in most cases. I think the problem is hard enough to not add another rule for fractions stacking

Comment: I believe there will be cases where you get overlap. For example, if you have a sum where the term becomes higher than 4 (e.g. multiple fractions, fractions of sums), and the sum has a long upper/lower bound, the upper/lower bound string could overlap with the term. How would that be resolved? Does the term have to be spaced from the sum to avoid overlap with the bounds?

Comment: Also, can the upper/lower bounds be formula again? For example, can the upper bound of a sum be a sum? Just asking unpleasant questions, btw. :) While this looks like a very fun problem, it's probably too much work for me.

Comment: @Reto Koradi Good questions. I'll edit the question to mention that the bounds are at most 4 characters long and can't be formulas. It could be cool to allow it but I think that would make the problem too tedious

Comment: [Related challenge.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/ascii-art-equation-visualizer)

Comment: I really hope someone comes up with a solution in LaTeX

Comment: @Zgarb: I would almost call this a duplicate of that challenge. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexA. It's borderline, but in my opinion this is sufficiently different, since it has fewer and different operations that must be supported, a clearer spec, and much easier parsing. It is actually possible to solve this challenge in less than 1000 bytes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Python 2, <del>656</del> <del>627</del> 618 bytes

```py
M=max
O=lambda l,o=2:[(p+o,c)for p,c in l]
def C(s,m=0):
 if''<s<'}'[m:]:f,w,h,d,s=C(s,1);F,W,H,D,s=C(s);e=M(d,D);return[O(f,e-d)+O(F,w*1j+e-D),w+W,M(h-d,H-D)+e,e,s]
 if'\\'!=s[:1]:return[[(0,s[:1])]*m,m,m,0,s[1:]]
 t=s[1]<'s';e=s[1]>'f';f,w,h,d,s=C(s[5+t+e:]);F,W,H,D,s=C(s[1+e:]);g=M(w,W);G=C('-'*g)[0]
 if e:f,w,h,F,W,H=F,W,H,f,w,h;g=4;p=C('|  |')[0];G=C('_'*(3+t))[0]+[O(C('/__,')[0])+[(1,'\\'),(1+3j,'`')],O(p,1)+O(p)][t]
 x=M(w,W,g);return[O(f,(x-w)/2*1j)+O(F,(x-W)/2*1j+h+3**e)+O(G,(x-g)/2*1j+h),x,h+3**e+H,h+e,s]
f,w,h,d,s=C(raw_input())
for y in range(h):print"".join(dict(f).get(y+x*1j,' ')for x in range(w))
```

Takes input on STDIN and writes output to STDOUT.

The program assumes that no other control sequence than `\frac`, `\sum` or `\prod` appears in the input (i.e., it won't show as normal text,) and that `~` doesn't appear as well (it [has a special meaning in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203686/what-does-the-tilde-character-do-in-math-mode) anyway.)
On the other hand, the program *does* support arbitrary formulas as limits for `\sum` and `\prod`.

### Explanation

It works just like TeX! (well, sort of...)
Each subformula (starting from single characters and building up to more complex formulas) is turned into a box, with an associated width, height and depth (baseline).
Boxes of simpler formulas are combined into bigger boxes to form complex formulas, and so on.
The contents of each box are represented as a list of position/character pairs, relative to the top-left corner of the box; when boxes are combined into a bigger box, the positions are offset according to the relative positions of the smaller boxes inside the bigger one, and the lists are concatenated.

Eventually, we end up with a top-level box, which is converted to a printable form.

---

To spice it up a little, the following version also supports square roots:

```js
M=max;R=range
O=lambda l,o=2:[(p+o,c)for p,c in l]
def C(s,m=0):
 if''<s<'}'[m:]:f,w,h,d,s=C(s,1);F,W,H,D,s=C(s);e=M(d,D);return[O(f,e-d)+O(F,w*1j+e-D),w+W,M(h-d,H-D)+e,e,s]
 if'\\'!=s[:1]:return[[(0,s[:1])]*m,m,m,0,s[1:]]
 t=s[1]<'s';e=s[1]>'f';f,w,h,d,z=C(s[5+t+e:])
 if'r'>s[2]:return[O(f,1j+h*1j+1)+O(C('_'*w)[0],1j+h*1j)+[(h,'\\')]+[(h-y+y*1j+1j,'/')for y in R(h)],w+1+h,h+1,d+1,z]
 F,W,H,D,s=C(z[1+e:]);g=M(w,W);G=C('-'*g)[0]
 if e:f,w,h,F,W,H=F,W,H,f,w,h;g=4;p=C('|  |')[0];G=C('_'*(3+t))[0]+[O(C('/__,')[0])+[(1,'\\'),(1+3j,'`')],O(p,1)+O(p)][t]
 x=M(w,W,g);return[O(f,(x-w)/2*1j)+O(F,(x-W)/2*1j+h+3**e)+O(G,(x-g)/2*1j+h),x,h+3**e+H,h+e,s]
f,w,h,d,s=C(raw_input())
for y in R(h):print"".join(dict(f).get(y+x*1j,' ')for x in R(w))
```

Examples:

- `\frac{-b +- \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}`

  ```
          _________
  -b +- \/b^2 - 4ac
  -----------------
         2a
  ```
- `|v| = \sqrt{ \sum_{i}^{} v[i]^2 }`

  ```
             _____________
            / ___
  |v| =    /  \  ` v[i]^2
          /   /__,
        \/     i
  ```

Comment: I have to say I'm thoroughly impressed! Tried to run `\prod_{i=1}^{\sum_{azededzeda}^{k}} \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m} 2j}{i + 1}` and it outputed everything correctly with no overlap, even though it wasn't required. Nice!

Comment: And you support square roots with only ~18% more bytes. Someone stop this man!

Comment: @Ell That makes sense! Nice work :)

Answer (score 23):

## LaTeX, <strike>540</strike> 532 characters

Disclaimer: This is not perfect and arguably does not count as a valid answer.

```
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\renewcommand{\sum}{\kern-1ex\displaystyle\mathop{\vphantom{\int}\begin{array}{l}\mbox{\underline{\hspace{12pt}}}\\ \mbox{\textbackslash}\hspace{8pt}`\\\mbox{/\underline{\hspace{8pt}},}\end{array}}\displaylimits}
\renewcommand{\prod}{\kern-1ex\displaystyle\mathop{\vphantom{\int}\begin{array}{c}\mbox{\underline{\hspace{16pt}}}\\|\ \ \ \ | \\| \ \ \ \ |\end{array}}\displaylimits}
\renewcommand{\frac}[2]{\mathop{\xleaders\hbox{-}\hfill\kern0pt}\limits^{#1}_{#2}}
\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{10}{10}
```

Some help from @Fatalize, see comments for details.

#### Test:

**Input:** `\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m} 2j}{i + 1}`

**Output:**

[image]

As you can see, the output does not exactly follow the spec. This may disqualify my answer, but I still think it's worth posting.

I wrote this on sharelatex.com.  You can play with it [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/558ecd2ae49358a12c6f5913).

Comment: Nice! I played with your code a bit and I think you can fix everything by changing your fraction to `\newcommand{\frac}[2]{\mathop{\xleaders\hbox{-}\hfill\kern0pt}\limits^{#1}_{#2}}`, adding `\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{10}{10}` after that (to prevent LaTeX from shrinking numerators and denominators), and by adding `\kern-1ex` before `\displaystyle` in your sum and product definition.